# Build APK - Error for Fragment buildConfig.class

Tags: android, android-studio

My app runs on the emulator, but when I want to build apk show the following error
[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you two file is exist

> build.gradle (Module.app)

you two dependencies just like him exists 
find him and remove only one line and clean and after rebuild and enjoy him !